# How to change input's font without resizing it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've an text input. I want to change font size on focus, and get the old value on blur. For example default is 14 and 10 when focused. But when I do this, the size of whole input is changing. How to avoid that?

UPDATE:
The task isn't so easy. What if I don't know the old width and height? I failed to obtain them using JQuery.

Comment: but what if I don't know the width and height? I'm writing a js library for arbitrary text inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>You can assign `width` and `height` style properties to the `input` element, e.g.:</s>

```
input {
    width: 150px;
    height: 32px;
}
```

Just be sure to use `px` and not `em`. :-)

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/iqubun) - Works in IE6 (!), Firefox 9, and Chrome 15, which suggests a fair degree of compatibility.

**Update** for edited question:

Same principal, but if you want to query the width and height and now that you've told us you're using jQuery:

CSS:

```
input {
    font-size: 14pt;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  var target = $("#target"),
      width  = target.width(),
      height = target.height();

  target.css({
    width: width + "px",
    height: height + "px"
  });

  target.focus(function() {
      this.style.fontSize = "10pt";
  });
  target.blur(function() {
    this.style.fontSize = "";
  });

});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/iqubun/2) - As with the one above, works in IE6, Firefox 9, and Chrome 15.

Comment: I could swear that I check that possibility, and it has some drawbacks. But I'll try it again in a moment. A major problem came up, and I've to hurry. I'll answer in some (short I hope) time.

Comment: seem to work! I don't know why before it wasn't working for me. Have to check it.

Answer (score 2):

The default size of the input is based on the character size. To avoid that you would have to specify the width and height for the input in absolute units, for example pixels.

Answer (score 1):

Example with jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/5DyNE/

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="foo" id="bar" />
```

**CSS**

```
#bar {
    width: 100px;
    height: 15px;
}
```

**JS**

```
var oldSize;
$('#bar').focus(function () {
    oldSize = $(this).css('font-size');
    $(this).css('font-size', 20);
});
$('#bar').blur(function () {
    $(this).css('font-size', oldSize);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set a fixed width and height of the input as well, and keep it the same no matter if the input has focus or not.

**Edit since the question was modified:**

If your doing it all with JavaScript, you could get the initial calculated width and height of the input and assign it as inline CSS. When you've done that, you should be fine modifying the font-size.

Comment: but all jquery's functions I tried, failed to do it precisely. There was always some pixel moving.

Comment: @santino How do you mean? Did it move when you assigned the inline css, or when you changed the font-size?

Comment: There are sometimes weird effects, for example: after focus and blur, the size of the input text is not the same as it was before, it's a pixel bigger in width. After a few clicks you can see it's growing.

Comment: @santino: That's interesting. Do you get that with the example in my answer? I don't.

Comment: @santino If you don't have that problem with T.J.'s answer either go with that, or provide some code samples and hopefully we can track down that bug.

Answer (score 0):

what you have to do to solve this problem is explicitly define the height of the input and then also define the font-size. For example:

```
input{
height:14px;
font-size:10px;
}
```